# Colspan sizing not working

Tags: html, html-table

When I run the code below, the proportions are all off. What do I need to change to get the right spacing? The columns on the bottom labeled 2 are about 4/5ths the size of the ones on top marked 4.

```
<body bgcolor="#14B3D9">
    <table width="100%" border="1" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <colgroup> <!-- Sets up table for spacing -->
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
        <col width="10%">
    </colgroup>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">4</td>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td colspan="4">4</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="10">10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">5</td>
        <td colspan="5">5</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
        <td colspan="6">6</td>
        <td colspan="2">2</td>
    </tr>


    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `table` markup violates the HTML table model, as you can see by using http://validator.org on the markup with HTML5 as the selected version; it says e.g. “Table column 2 established by element col has no cells beginning in it.” This means that anything may happen.

You should correct the markup so that for each column, there is at least one cell that begins in it, as required by the table model. Alternatively, as this seems to be an attempt at complicated layout with `table`, rather than tabular data, consider other options such as CSS layout.